# Retrieving Editted Data with Qtablewidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to retrieve the editted data from a pyqt5 qtablewidget and am struggling to understand how to do this. My simple code is shown below:

```
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        DBL_MAX = 1.7976931348623157e308
        editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent, minimum=-DBL_MAX, maximum=DBL_MAX, decimals=323)
        return editor


class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args)
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

        delegate = Delegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for j, (key, values) in enumerate(sorted(self.z.items())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
                newitem.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
                self.setItem(i, j, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
    def slot(self):
         row= self.tableWidget.currentItem()
         print(str(row))


def main(args):

    z = {
        "Let's Sum This Row 1": [0, 0],
        "Let's Sum This Row 2": [0, 0],
    }

    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, 2, 2)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)

a = z
sum1=a[0][0]+a[0][1]
sum2=a[1][0]+a[1][1]

print(sum1)
print(sum2)
```

In my simple example my initial z data is a zeros. Let's say that the user changes the first rows to 1's and the second row to 2's.

The end output I want is sum1 = 2 and sum2 = 4.

How do i tell my program to read the end user editted matrix and store that back to a variable so that I can do more work further on in my program?

From my research, it looks like `itemchanged` may do the trick, but I am struggling to understand how to implement this in my code.

Comment: add `self.itemchanged.connect(self.slot)` after `self.resizeRowsToContents()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited your code to add itemChanged and calculate
[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QStyledItemDelegate, QDoubleSpinBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize)
import sys


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        DBL_MAX = 1.7976931348623157e308
        editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent, minimum=-DBL_MAX, maximum=DBL_MAX, decimals=323)
        return editor


class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        delegate = Delegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for j, (key, values) in enumerate(sorted(self.z.items())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
                newitem.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
                newitem
                self.setItem(i, j, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

    def slot(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentItem()
        print(str(row))


def main(args):
    z = {
        "Let's Sum This Row 1": [0, 0],
        "Let's Sum This Row 2": [0, 0],
    }

    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, 2, 2)

    def _calculate():
        for j in range(table.columnCount()):
            counter = 0
            for i in range(table.rowCount()):
                counter = counter + int(table.item(i, j).data(0))
            print(f"col{j}: sum={counter}")

    table.itemChanged.connect(_calculate)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```